Renormalization in Background field gauge
The purpose of this question is not very straightforward to explain. So, I just state the question. If we use Background field gauge for renormalization, due to the QED-like Ward identities, the derivation of counterterms become easier. For instance, the two-point vertex function for $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{Z}$ can be written as
$$
\Gamma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_{\mu\nu}=i(g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}\Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_T-i\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2} \Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_L
$$
where $\Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_L$, $\Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_L$ are the self energy of this $\hat{A}\hat{Z}$ propagation with a intermediate fermion loop. From the Ward identity, we can show $\Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_L=0$. Now, the article http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9410338 in the eqn (43) writes the longitudinal self-energy with counterterms as
$$
\Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z},Renorm}_L= \Sigma^{\hat{A}\hat{Z}}_L-\frac{m_Z^2}{2}\delta Z_{ZA}.\tag{43}
$$
I do not understand how the renormalized self-energy gets this form. In particular, how this counterterm combination arises. Help is appriciated.
